# javascript associative array, remove index only

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I got a small problem in javascript and i can't resolve it...i'm pretty sure it's stupid but :

i've got an array like this :

```
 test =  [1: Array[4], 500: Array[1], 1000: Array[1]]
```

and i'd like to get this :

```
 array = [test[1], test[500], test[1000]];
```

I thought Jquery map and makearray could help me but they are running from 2 to 499 etc...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how did you construct test?

Comment: a little bit complicated but i can get an array like : test_i = [1,500,1000] if it's your questions. I thought of it but don't like it..

Comment: You should distinguish between an *array*, which is indexed from 0 to *count* without gaps, automatically growing, and *objects* which are key-value pairs. Your problem should be fixed if `test` is properly instantiated as an object instead of an array. An array can not have gaps, so your results are logical.

Comment: it's not very clear what you want to do at all. the first snippet you posted looks like some kind of variable dump, while the second looks like valid javascript, except with totally different variable names. are you trying to put elements of the array `test` into a new array called `array`?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes : so i should convert test into object then with an $.each, push element into array[] ? I'll try :) sgroves: yes my second snippet is a new array containing test[] element

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes , transformt test into an object is also a good option. Didn't think of it..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a regular array out of an object with properties and values like:

```
// test object
var test =  {1: "Hello", 500: "World", 1000: "Bye"};

// convert
var result = [];
for(var i in test) {
    if(test.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        result.push(test[i]);
    }
}

console.log(result); // --> ["Hello", "World", "Bye"]
```

Comment: it works :) i could never imagine that for will only pass the right index...Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is :

```
var test = [];
test[1] = 4;
test[500] = 1;
test[1000] = 1;
```

Or maybe :

```
test = {1: 4, 500:1, 1000:1};
```